# Magento 1.9 REST API getting problem when trying to get data

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I am using Magento 1.9, REST API getting problem when trying to get data using API. Here is the screenshot . If any one here to help. it's ok on guest user and customer user but problem on admin .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create rest.php file in you root folder

```
<?php

$magentoUrl = "http://yoursite.com/subfolder/";
$consumerKey = 'consumer Key';
$consumerSecret = 'consumer Secret';



$callbackUrl = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "{$magentoUrl}/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = "{$magentoUrl}/admin/oauth_authorize";
$accessTokenRequestUrl = "{$magentoUrl}/oauth/token";
$apiUrl = '{$magentoUrl}/api/rest';


session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "Consumer Key: " . print_r($consumerKey, true). "\n";
        echo "Consumer Secret: " . print_r($consumerSecret, true). "\n";
        echo "\n\n";
        echo "Token Key: " . print_r($_SESSION['token'], true). "\n";
        echo "Token Secret: " . print_r($_SESSION['secret'], true). "\n\n";
        unset($_SESSION['state']);
        unset($_SESSION['secret']);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Use this code and yoursite.com/rest.php

Done
and get Authorize your app . Now you can see your Token Key and Token Secret . use it any where ...

Comment: It is not working for me...! same as above mention please give me other solutions